# Sign In integration issue, can't find class CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

I am currently trying to integrate the Sign In functionality from aws into my android app. I followed all the instructions provided to me by AWS, downloaded and inserted there auto generated code, but still get an error.

Here is the Location:

```
...\app\src\main\java\com\amazonaws\mobile\user\signin\SignInManager.java
```

My Error:

> (49, 15) error: cannot find symbol class CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider

Auto generated code snippet that throws the error:

```
    // Initialize Cognito User Pools SDK.
    final CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider cognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider =
            new CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider(context);
    addSignInProvider(cognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider);
```

Where do I find this class and how do I integrate it in my app?
I tried googling for it, but I can't find anything relevant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getting started guide is not complete. I had the same problem. 
You can find this class in the sample application of the User Sign-In step.

Answer (score 0):

just add these dependencies and sync your project!

```
compile('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.2')
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.4.2'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.4.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

`CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider` is ditributed as part of `aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools` library. Please import the following library and you should be able to do it.

```
compile ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.6.+') { transitive = true; }
```

Now you can register this provider with the IdentityManager as follows:

```
IdentityManager.getDefaultIdentityManager().addSignInProvider(CognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.class);
```